Rewriting the java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap to a version without concurrency constructs
I have essentially rewrote the java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap into a version without concurrency constructs (java.lang.invoke.VarHandle):
com.github.coderodde.util.SkipListMap.java:
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements a map sorted by keys using skip lists.
 * 
 * @version 1.0.0 (May 27, 2024)
 * @since 1.0.0 (May 27, 2024)
 */
public final class SkipListMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V>
                                     implements Map<K, V> {
    
    private static final class Node<K,V> {
        final K key;
        V val;
        Node<K,V> next;
        Node(K key, V value, Node<K,V> next) {
            this.key = key;
            this.val = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
    
    private static final class Index<K,V> {
        final Node<K,V> node;
        final Index<K,V> down;
        Index<K,V> right;
        Index(Node<K,V> node, Index<K,V> down, Index<K,V> right) {
            this.node = node;
            this.down = down;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }
    
    private final class SkipListIterator implements Iterator<K> {

        private Node<K, V> node = head != null ? head.node.next : null;
        private int iterated;
        
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterated < size;
        }

        @Override
        public K next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            
            K ret = node.key;
            node = node.next;
            iterated++;
            return ret;
        }
    }

    private Index<K,V> head;
    private int size;
    private final Random random = new Random(13);
    private final Comparator<K> comparator;
    
    public SkipListMap(Comparator<K> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }
    
    public SkipListMap() {
        this.comparator = null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return doGet(key);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return doGet(key) != null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        
        if (key == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        
        Comparator<? super K> cmp = comparator;
        
        for (;;) {
            Index<K,V> h; Node<K,V> b;
            int levels = 0;               
            
            if ((h = head) == null) {     
                Node<K,V> base = new Node<>(null, null, null);
                h = new Index<>(base, null, null);
                
                if (head == null) {
                    head = h;
                    b = base;
                } else {
                    b = null;
                }
            } else {
                for (Index<K,V> q = h, r, d;;) { 
                    while ((r = q.right) != null) {
                        Node<K,V> p;
                        K k = null;
                        
                        if ((p = r.node) == null 
                                || (k = p.key) == null 
                                || p.val == null) {
                        
                            if (q.right == r) {
                                q.right = r.right;
                            }
                        } else if (cpr(cmp, key, k) > 0) {
                            q = r;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if ((d = q.down) != null) {
                        ++levels;
                        q = d;
                    } else {
                        b = q.node;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if (b != null) {
                Node<K,V> z = null;
                
                for (;;) {                       
                    Node<K,V> n, p; 
                    K k; 
                    V v; 
                    int c;
                    
                    if ((n = b.next) == null) {
                        c = -1;
                    } else if ((k = n.key) == null) {
                        break;
                    } else if ((v = n.val) == null) {
                        unlinkNode(b, n);
                        c = 1;
                    } else if ((c = cpr(cmp, key, k)) > 0) {
                        b = n;
                    } else if (c == 0) {
                        if (n.val == v) {
                            n.val = value;
                            return v;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (c < 0) {
                        if (b.next == n) {
                            b.next = p = new Node<>(key, value, n);
                            z = p;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (z != null) {
                    long rnd = random.nextLong();
                    
                    if ((rnd & 0x3) == 0) {       // add indices with 1/4 prob
                        int skips = levels;    
                        Index<K,V> x = null;
                    
                        for (;;) {               
                            x = new Index<>(z, x, null);
                            
                            if (rnd >= 0L || --skips < 0) {
                                break;
                            } else {
                                rnd <<= 1;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if (addIndices(h, skips, x, cmp) 
                                && skips < 0 
                                && head == h) {   
                            
                            Index<K,V> hx = new Index<>(z, x, null);
                            Index<K,V> nh = new Index<>(h.node, h, hx);
                            
                            if (head == h) {
                                head = nh;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if (z.val == null) {
                            findPredecessor(key, cmp);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    size++;
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        return doRemove(key, null);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        
        if (!(o instanceof Map)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        Map<K, V> otherMap = (Map<K, V>) o;
        
        if (size != otherMap.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        Iterator<K> iter1 = otherMap.keySet().iterator();
        Iterator<K> iter2 = new SkipListIterator();
        
        for (;;) {
            boolean b1 = iter1.hasNext();
            boolean b2 = iter2.hasNext();
            
            if (b1 && !b2) {
                return false;
            }
            
            if (!b1 && b2) {
                return false;
            }
            
            if (!b1 && !b2) {
                return true;
            }
            
            K key1 = iter1.next();
            K key2 = iter2.next();
            
            if (!key1.equals(key2)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
    
    private V doGet(Object key) {
        Index<K,V> q;
        
        if (key == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        
        V result = null;
        
        if ((q = head) != null) {
            outer: 
            for (Index<K,V> r, d;;) {
                while ((r = q.right) != null) {
                    Node<K,V> p; 
                    K k; 
                    V v; 
                    int c;
                    
                    if ((p = r.node) == null 
                            || (k = p.key) == null 
                            || (v = p.val) == null) {
                        
                        if (q.right == r) {
                            q.right = r.right;
                        }
                    } else if ((c = cpr(comparator, key, k)) > 0) {
                        q = r;
                    } else if (c == 0) {
                        result = v;
                        break outer;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                if ((d = q.down) != null) {
                    q = d;
                } else {
                    Node<K,V> b, n;
                    
                    if ((b = q.node) != null) {
                        while ((n = b.next) != null) {
                            V v; 
                            int c;
                            K k = n.key;
                            
                            if ((v = n.val) == null 
                                    || k == null 
                                    || (c = cpr(comparator, key, k)) > 0) {
                                b = n;
                            } else {
                                if (c == 0) {
                                    result = v;
                                }
                                    
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    private Node<K,V> findPredecessor(Object key, Comparator<? super K> cmp) {
        Index<K,V> q;
        
        if ((q = head) == null || key == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            for (Index<K,V> r, d;;) {
                while ((r = q.right) != null) {
                    Node<K,V> p; 
                    K k = null;
                    
                    if ((p = r.node) == null 
                            || (k = p.key) == null 
                            || p.val == null) {
                        
                        if (q.right == r) {
                            q.right = r.right;
                        }
                    } else if (cpr(cmp, key, k) > 0) {
                        q = r;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                if ((d = q.down) != null) {
                    q = d;
                } else {
                    return q.node;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static <K,V> boolean addIndices(Index<K,V> q, int skips, Index<K,V> x,
                                    Comparator<? super K> cmp) {
        Node<K,V> z; 
        K key;
        
        if (x != null
                && (z = x.node) != null 
                && (key = z.key) != null 
                &&q != null) {                     
            
            boolean retrying = false;
            
            for (;;) {
                Index<K,V> r, d; 
                int c;
                
                if ((r = q.right) != null) {
                    Node<K,V> p; 
                    K k;
                    
                    if ((p = r.node) == null 
                            || (k = p.key) == null 
                            || p.val == null) {
                        
                        if (q.right == r) {
                            q.right = r.right;
                        }
                        
                        c = 0;
                    } else if ((c = cpr(cmp, key, k)) > 0) {
                        q = r;
                    } else if (c == 0) {
                        break;          
                    }
                } else {
                    c = -1;
                }

                if (c < 0) {
                    if ((d = q.down) != null && skips > 0) {
                        --skips;
                        q = d;
                    } else if (d != null 
                                && !retrying 
                                && !addIndices(d, 0, x.down, cmp)) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        x.right = r;
                        
                        if (q.right == r) {
                            q.right = x;
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            retrying = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    private static <K,V> void unlinkNode(Node<K,V> b, Node<K,V> n) {
        if (b != null && n != null) {
            Node<K,V> f, p;
            
            for (;;) {
                if ((f = n.next) != null && f.key == null) {
                    p = f.next;
                    break;
                } else if (n.next == f) {
                    n.next = new Node<>(null, null, f);
                    p = f;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (b.next == n) {
                b.next = p;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private final V doRemove(Object key, Object value) {
        if (key == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        
        Comparator<? super K> cmp = comparator;
        V result = null;
        Node<K,V> b;
        
        outer: 
        while ((b = findPredecessor(key, cmp)) != null && result == null) {
            for (;;) {
                Node<K,V> n; 
                K k;
                V v; 
                int c;
                
                if ((n = b.next) == null) {
                    break outer;
                } else if ((k = n.key) == null) {
                    break;
                } else if ((v = n.val) == null) {
                    unlinkNode(b, n);
                } else if ((c = cpr(cmp, key, k)) > 0) {
                    b = n;
                } else if (c < 0) {
                    break outer;
                } else if (value != null && !value.equals(v)) {
                    break outer;
                } else if (n.val == v) {
                    n.val = null;
                    result = v;
                    unlinkNode(b, n);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (result != null) {
            tryReduceLevel();
            size--;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
 
    private void tryReduceLevel() {
        Index<K,V> h, d, e;
        if ((h = head) != null && h.right == null &&
            (d = h.down) != null && d.right == null &&
            (e = d.down) != null && e.right == null) {
            
            if (head == h) {
                head = d;
            } else {
                return;
            }
            
            if (h.right != null) {
                if (head == d) {
                    head = h;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    static int cpr(Comparator c, Object x, Object y) {
        return (c != null) ? c.compare(x, y) : ((Comparable)x).compareTo(y);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SkipListMap<Integer, String> l =
                new SkipListMap<>(new Comparator<Integer>(){
                    
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });
        
        System.out.println("a");
        l.put(1, "one");
        System.out.println("b");
        l.put(2, "two");
        System.out.println("c");
        
        System.out.println(l.containsKey(1));
        System.out.println(l.containsKey(2));
        System.out.println(l.containsKey(3));
    }
}

com.github.coderodde.util.SkipListMapTest.java:
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class SkipListMapTest {

    private static final Comparator<Integer> CMP = new Comparator<>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    };
    
    @Test
    public void containsKey() {
        SkipListMap<Integer, String> list = new SkipListMap<>(CMP);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            assertFalse(list.containsKey(i));
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            assertNull(list.put(i, "Hello"));
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            assertTrue(list.containsKey(i));
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    public void get() {
        SkipListMap<Integer, String> list = new SkipListMap<>(CMP);
        
        assertNull(list.put(1, "1"));
        assertNull(list.put(2, "2"));
        assertNull(list.put(3, "3"));
        assertNull(list.put(4, "4"));
        
        assertEquals("1", list.get(1));
        assertEquals("2", list.get(2));
        assertEquals("3", list.get(3));
        assertEquals("4", list.get(4));
        
        assertNull(list.get(0));
        assertNull(list.get(5));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void remove() {
        SkipListMap<Integer, String> list = new SkipListMap<>(CMP);
        
        for (int i : new int[]{ 1, 3, 5, 7 }) {
            list.put(i, Integer.toString(i));
        }
        
        assertNull(list.remove(0));
        assertNull(list.remove(2));
        assertNull(list.remove(4));
        assertNull(list.remove(6));
        assertNull(list.remove(8));
        
        for (int i : new int[]{ 1, 3, 5, 7 }) {
            assertEquals(Integer.toString(i), list.remove(i));
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    public void bruteForce() {
        SkipListMap<Integer, String> list1 = new SkipListMap<>(CMP);
        Map<Integer, String> list2 = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>(CMP);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            assertFalse(list1.containsKey(i));
            assertNull(list1.get(i));
            
            assertFalse(list2.containsKey(i));
            assertNull(list2.get(i));
            
            assertNull(list1.put(i, Integer.toString(i)));
            assertNull(list2.put(i, Integer.toString(i)));
            
            assertTrue(list1.containsKey(i));
            assertEquals(Integer.toString(i), list1.get(i));
            assertTrue(list2.containsKey(i));
            assertEquals(Integer.toString(i), list2.get(i));
        }
        
        for (int i = -100; i < 0; i++) {
            assertNull(list1.get(i));
            assertFalse(list1.containsKey(i));
            
            assertNull(list2.get(i));
            assertFalse(list2.containsKey(i));
            
            assertNull(list1.remove(i));
            assertNull(list2.remove(i));
        }
        
        for (int i = 1000; i < 1100; i++) {
            assertNull(list1.get(i));
            assertFalse(list1.containsKey(i));
            
            assertNull(list2.get(i));
            assertFalse(list2.containsKey(i));
            
            assertNull(list1.remove(i));
            assertNull(list2.remove(i));
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            assertEquals(Integer.toString(i), list1.remove(i));
            assertEquals(Integer.toString(i), list2.remove(i));
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    public void versatile() {
        Random rnd = new Random(10);
        Map<Integer, String> list1 = new SkipListMap<>(CMP);
        Map<Integer, String> list2 = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>(CMP);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            assertTrue(list1.equals(list2));
            
            int coin = rnd.nextInt(100);
            int key = rnd.nextInt(150);
            
            if (list1.isEmpty() || coin < 50) {
                list1.put(key, Integer.toString(key));
                list2.put(key, Integer.toString(key));
            } else if (coin < 70) {
                assertEquals(list2.remove(key), 
                             list1.remove(key));
            } else {
                assertEquals(list1.containsKey(key), 
                             list2.containsKey(key));
                
                assertEquals(list2.get(key), list1.get(key));
            }
        }
        
        assertTrue(list1.equals(list2));
    }
}

SkipListComparison.java:
import com.github.coderodde.util.SkipListMap;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap;

public class SkipListComparison {
    
    private static final String INSERT   = "insert";
    private static final String CONTAINS = "contains";
    private static final String DELETE   = "delete";
    private static final Comparator<Integer> CMP = new Comparator<>() {
        
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(02);
        }
    };

    private static final Map<String, Long> DM_SKIP_LIST = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<String, Long> DM_C_SKIP_LIST = new HashMap<>();
    private static final Map<String, Long> DM_TREE_MAP = new HashMap<>();
    
    private static final Map<Integer, Boolean> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(CMP);
    private static final Map<Integer, Boolean> concurrentSkipListMap = 
            new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>(CMP);
    
    private static final Map<Integer, Boolean> skipListMap =
            new SkipListMap<>(CMP);
    
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 10;
    
    static {
        DM_SKIP_LIST.put(INSERT, 0L);
        DM_SKIP_LIST.put(DELETE, 0L);
        DM_SKIP_LIST.put(CONTAINS, 0L);
        
        DM_C_SKIP_LIST.put(INSERT, 0L);
        DM_C_SKIP_LIST.put(DELETE, 0L);
        DM_C_SKIP_LIST.put(CONTAINS, 0L);
        
        DM_TREE_MAP.put(INSERT, 0L);
        DM_TREE_MAP.put(DELETE, 0L);
        DM_TREE_MAP.put(CONTAINS, 0L);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Warming up...");
        warmup();
        System.out.println("Warming up done!");
        System.out.printf("Doing %d benchmark iterations.\n", ITERATIONS);
        
        final int totalIterations = 10;
        
        for (int iter = 0; iter < totalIterations; iter++) { 
            System.out.printf("Iteration: %d.\n", iter);
            
            Integer[] input = getInputIntegerArray();

            long ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (Integer i : input) {
                treeMap.put(i, Boolean.TRUE);
            }

            long tb = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            DM_TREE_MAP.put(INSERT, tb - ta);

            ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (Integer i : input) {
                concurrentSkipListMap.put(i, Boolean.TRUE);
            }
            
            tb = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            DM_C_SKIP_LIST.put(INSERT, tb - ta);

            ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (Integer i : input) {
                skipListMap.put(i, Boolean.TRUE);
            }

            tb = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            DM_SKIP_LIST.put(INSERT, tb - ta);

            ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                treeMap.containsKey(input[i]);
            }

            tb = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            DM_TREE_MAP.put(CONTAINS, DM_TREE_MAP.get(CONTAINS) + tb - ta);

            ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                concurrentSkipListMap.containsKey(input[i]);
            }

            tb = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            DM_C_SKIP_LIST.put(CONTAINS, DM_C_SKIP_LIST.get(CONTAINS) + tb - ta);

            ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                skipListMap.containsKey(input[i]);
            }

            tb = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            DM_SKIP_LIST.put(CONTAINS, DM_SKIP_LIST.get(CONTAINS) + tb - ta);

            Random random = new Random(10);

            ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                treeMap.remove(random.nextInt());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                treeMap.remove(input[i]);
            }

            tb = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            DM_TREE_MAP.put(DELETE, DM_TREE_MAP.get(DELETE) + tb - ta);

            ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                concurrentSkipListMap.remove(random.nextInt());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                concurrentSkipListMap.remove(input[i]);
            }

            tb = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            DM_C_SKIP_LIST.put(DELETE, DM_C_SKIP_LIST.get(DELETE) + tb - ta);

            ta = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                skipListMap.remove(random.nextInt());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                skipListMap.remove(input[i]);
            }

            tb = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            DM_SKIP_LIST.put(DELETE, DM_SKIP_LIST.get(DELETE) + tb - ta);
        }
        
        printMapStatistics(DM_SKIP_LIST);
        printMapStatistics(DM_C_SKIP_LIST);
        printMapStatistics(DM_TREE_MAP);
        
        printTotalStatistics();
    }
    
    private static String getDataStructureName(Map<String, Long> m) {
        if (m == DM_TREE_MAP) {
            return "TreeMap";
        }
        
        if (m == DM_C_SKIP_LIST) {
            return "ConcurrentSkipListMap";
        }
        
        if (m == DM_SKIP_LIST) {
            return "SkipListMap";
        }
        
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    
    private static long getAverageDuration(Map<String, Long> map, 
                                           String operationName, 
                                           int iterations) {
        return map.get(operationName) / iterations;
    }
    
    private static void printMapStatistics(Map<String, Long> map) {
        
        System.out.printf("%s.%s: %d milliseconds.\n",
                          getDataStructureName(map),
                          INSERT,
                          getAverageDuration(map, INSERT, ITERATIONS));
        
        System.out.printf("%s.%s: %d milliseconds.\n",
                          getDataStructureName(map),
                          CONTAINS,
                          getAverageDuration(map, CONTAINS, ITERATIONS));
        
        System.out.printf("%s.%s: %d milliseconds.\n",
                          getDataStructureName(map),
                          DELETE,
                          getAverageDuration(map, DELETE, ITERATIONS));
    }
    
    private static long getTotalDuration(Map<String, Long> m) {
        long duration = getAverageDuration(m, CONTAINS, ITERATIONS);
        duration += getAverageDuration(m, INSERT, ITERATIONS);
        duration += getAverageDuration(m, DELETE, ITERATIONS);
        
        return duration;
    }
    
    private static void printTotalStatistics() {
        
        System.out.printf("TreeMap: %d milliseconds.\n", 
                          getTotalDuration(DM_TREE_MAP));
        
        System.out.printf("ConcurrentSkipListMap: %d milliseconds.\n", 
                          getTotalDuration(DM_C_SKIP_LIST));
        
        System.out.printf("SkipListMap: %d milliseconds.\n", 
                          getTotalDuration(DM_SKIP_LIST));
    }

    private static Integer[] getInputIntegerArray() {
        Random random = new Random(1);
        Integer[] input = new Integer[1_000_000];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            input[i] = random.nextInt(1_000_000);
        }

        return input;
    }
    
    private static void warmup() {
        
        Random random = new Random(100L);
        Integer[] input = getInputIntegerArray();

        for (Integer i : input) {
            treeMap.put(i, Boolean.TRUE);
        }
        
        for (Integer i : input) {
            concurrentSkipListMap.put(i, Boolean.TRUE);
        }

        for (Integer i : input) {
            skipListMap.put(i, Boolean.TRUE);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            treeMap.containsKey(input[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            concurrentSkipListMap.containsKey(input[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            skipListMap.containsKey(input[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            treeMap.remove(random.nextInt());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            treeMap.remove(input[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            concurrentSkipListMap.remove(random.nextInt());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            concurrentSkipListMap.remove(input[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            skipListMap.remove(random.nextInt());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            skipListMap.remove(input[i]);
        }
    }
}

Typical output
SkipListMap.insert: 55 milliseconds.
SkipListMap.contains: 128 milliseconds.
SkipListMap.delete: 294 milliseconds.
ConcurrentSkipListMap.insert: 29 milliseconds.
ConcurrentSkipListMap.contains: 154 milliseconds.
ConcurrentSkipListMap.delete: 468 milliseconds.
TreeMap.insert: 38 milliseconds.
TreeMap.contains: 197 milliseconds.
TreeMap.delete: 348 milliseconds.

TreeMap: 583 milliseconds.
ConcurrentSkipListMap: 651 milliseconds.
SkipListMap: 477 milliseconds.


Critique request
Please, tell me any commentary on how to improve my result.

There are conditions that always seem true: q.right == r in findPredecessor() and head == h in tryReduceLevel().

I'm not sure if this clears the ownership threshold. The bulk of the code, at least the most important bits, seem to be copied from  the OpenJDK codebase so there's no point in reviewing it (also I hate the code style, it looks like it was written by a CompSci professor of algorithm analysis). Also you left out the copyright notice which would mean the code is in breach of the GPL...

@Torben - more accurately, it's the act of publishing here (under the CC licence) which breaches the requirements of the GPL.

In the interest of debug-ability, the NullPointerExceptions thrown at the start of put could use some error messages to help people figure out whether the key or the value was null
We can simplify our comparisons by defaulting to Comparator.naturalOrder() instead of null. If we do this, the cpr helper function doesn't seem to need to exist.
The no-parameter constructor makes it possible to create a map with a non-Comparable key type without providing a Comparator. Such an object is obviously ill-behaved and should not be constructible. Using a factory method with a type like <K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> SkipListMap<K, V> instead of the no-parameter constructor (and making the parametrised constructor throw if passed null) we can help people avoid such issues.
doGet doesn't need a labeled loop. The only path that breaks (or, for that matter, continues) the outer loop does so immediately before setting the value to be returned, and the only thing that happens after the loop is returning that value. So result = v; break outer; can just be replaced with return v;
I find while (true) clearer than for (;;), though I acknowledge that this is a matter of opinion.
Assignments in ifs feel clever but provide little actual benefit compared to just adding another block. E.g
} else {
    c = comparator.compare(key, k);
    if (c > 0) q = r;
    else if (c == 0) return v;
    else break;
}

equals is incorrect. It considers two maps equal if they iterate over their keys in the same order, regardless of which values they map those keys to, but considers them unequal if they map the same keys to the same values but iterate over their keys in a different order (meaning two SkipListMaps are unequal if they use different comparators). By implementing Map we guarantee that this is not how our equals should behave.
head is never null except at the very start. And the very first thing we do when accessing the map is assign an actual value to head. So I see no reason to not just do that at construction time so we can stop worrying about null.
A lot of variables are declared together, often in a larger scope than where they are actually used. This sometimes makes is hard to figure out when and where the variables are actually used. I would suggest instead declaring variables closer to when they are initialized and used. Several variables could even be inlined and deleted entirely - this might not always be clearer than well-named variables, but it is clearer than poorly-named ones.
Speaking of variable names, many consist of a single letter. Rename these.
There are a lot of conditions that, in the absence of concurrency, boil down to checking if some field is the same as itself (the if (head == null) check nested inside another if (head == null) block is one example. an if (r == q.right) almost immediately after an r = q.right assignment is another). As we provide no guarantees about concurrency we can make our code simpler and clearer by removing such checks.
